# Sublime theme regex not working when the line doesn't start with a white space

Tags: regex, sublimetext, sublimetext3

I'm trying to customize a SublimeText theme for [pandoc's markdown syntax](http://johnmacfarlane.net/pandoc/demo/example9/pandocs-markdown.html). I want to highlight footnotes references inside paragraphs.

The syntax for footnotes is : `[^foo]`

I have the following regex : `\[\^(.*)\]` in my tmLanguage file :

```
<dict>
    <key>comment</key>
    <string>Footnotes references</string>
    <key>match</key>
    <string>\[\^(.*)\]</string>
    <key>name</key>
    <string>meta.paragraph.markdown.footnote</string>
</dict>
```

Here's the result :

[image]
(sorry, I can't insert images...)

Line 149: just the reference. It works.

Line 150: white space and the reference. It works.

Line 151: white space, random text, the reference. It works

Line 152: white space, random text, white space, the reference, white space, random text. It works.

Line 153: white space, random text, the reference, random text. It works.

Line 154: NO white space, the reference. IT FAILS.

Line 155: same as line 149, it should work but it fails... I guess because of line 154.

Line 156: blank

Line 157: same as line 149 and 155, it works again...

It seems that my regex or Sublime or something needs a leading white space. Adding the multiline option `(?w)` doesn't help.

Do you have any idea of what's going wrong here and how to fix it ?

Answer (score 0):

It could be a problem with the `(.*)`, because it matches any single character (including `[` and `]`).

Try to use a different symbol and post the results please.

For example:

```
\[\^(\w*)\]
```